# Handling missing data while reading from s3 in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using encoders to read the data from s3 to a DF, but a few fields specified in the encoder entity are missing in the input data and I am getting

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
```

How can I handle this scenario?

```java
Encoder<Entity> sEncoder = Encoders.bean(Entity.class);
Dataset<Entity> sAggregates =sparkSession.read().json(inputPaths.get(0).as(sEncoder);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark fails to write and then read JSON formatted data with nullable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042632/spark-fails-to-write-and-then-read-json-formatted-data-with-nullable-column)